# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (Java, Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, multidimensional-array, compare

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] alunos = new String[100][2];
    String[][] grelhaAvaliacao = null;
    double classificacoes[][] = null;
    int op, numAl = 0;
    do {
        op = menu();
        switch(op) {
            case 1:
                numAl = carregarFicheiro(alunos, numAl);
                break;
            case 2:
                numAl = lerInformação(alunos, numAl);
                break;
            case 3:
                escreverFicheiroAlunos(alunos, numAl);
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Introduza uma opção válida!");
                break;
        }
    } while(op != 0);
}

public static int lerInformação(String[][] alunos, int numAl) {
    do {
        System.out.print("Nome do Aluno: ");
        alunos[numAl][0] = ler.next();
        System.out.print("Número do Aluno: ");
        ler.nextLine();
        alunos[numAl][1] = ler.next();
        numAl++;
    } while(numAl < alunos.length && (!alunos[numAl][0].equalsIgnoreCase("FIM")));
    return numAl;
}
```

---

> Output: 
>   Menu:
>   1.Carregar ficheiro alunos 
>   2.Inserir Informações para Alunos 
>   3.Gravar alterações ao ficeiro alunos 
>   4.Carregar ficheiro Grelha 
>   5.Mostrar Grelha 
>   6.Inserir informações de cotação 
>   7.Mostrar informação completa 
>   8.Nota final >=50% 
>   9.Apresentar HTML 
>   0.Sair
>   Opção: 2
>   Nome do Aluno: joao santos
>   Número do Aluno: 1140296
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   aplicação_final.Aplicação_Final.lerInformação(Aplicação_Final.java:73)
>     at aplicação_final.Aplicação_Final.main(Aplicação_Final.java:23) 
>   Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)

---

> So here is my problem guys, that error. I know it is because of the
>   while statement, in this part exactly
>   (!alunos[numAl][0].equalsIgnoreCase("FIM")) I just don't understand
>   why, this is a program i must program for school, it has more
>   functionalities, but they are not needed here i believe since the
>   error is right there, this method lerInformaçao, basicly asks the user
>   to input the name of a student and then asks for his school number(the
>   student's) and it saves one on the column 0 of a bidimensional array
>   and the other in the column 1, the part i mentioned from the while
>   statement is supposed to end the reading when the user input the word
>   FIM(end in portuguese), but it causes that error, any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you use a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)? `(!"FIM".equalsIgnoreCase(alunos[numAl][0]))`

Comment: No, it doesn't work with the YODA condition, it just keeps asking for more input, the exception is gone, but it doesn't stop when i input FIM, basically it's like there was only while(numAl < alunos.length);

Comment: Perhaps it's time to learn to use the [debugger](https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!alunos[numAl][0].equalsIgnoreCase("FIM"))` will never evaluate how you want. When the condition is evaluated, `alunos[numAl][0]` is always checking against a NULL entry, because you've incremented `numAl`. The reason the YODA condition did something different for you is because "FIM" doesn't equal NULL, which means `!"FIM".equalsIgnoreCase(alunos[numAl][0]);` will always evaluate to TRUE, so the loop continues based solely on the `.length()` condition.

Try this:

```
public static int lerInformação(String[][] alunos, int numAl) {
do {
    System.out.print("Nome do Aluno: ");
    alunos[numAl][0] = ler.next();
    System.out.print("Número do Aluno: ");
    ler.nextLine();
    alunos[numAl][1] = ler.next();
    numAl++;
} while(numAl < alunos.length && (!alunos[numAl-1][0].equalsIgnoreCase("FIM"))); //numAl - 1, instead.
return numAl;
```

}

By using `numAl - 1` you're checking against the most recent user input, which happened before you incremented `numAl`. However, a better solution would be:

```
public static int lerInformação(String[][] alunos, int numAl) {
do {
    System.out.print("Nome do Aluno: ");
    alunos[numAl][0] = ler.next();
    if(alunos[numAl][0].equalsIgnoreCase("FIM") {
      break;
    }
    System.out.print("Número do Aluno: ");
    ler.nextLine();
    alunos[numAl][1] = ler.next();
    numAl++;
} while(numAl < alunos.length);
return numAl;
}
```

This way, you don't keep running unnecessary code(such as prompting for Numero do Aluno), once the user has entered FIM. The `break` will exit the loop immediately.

However, you'll still have to address the fact that you're storing a command (FIM), inside the user-generated array of `alunos`, which is bad practice. You can solve that for updating the relevant code to something like:

```
 String userInput = ler.next();
    if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("FIM") {
      break;
    }
    else {
     alunos[numAl][0] = userInput;
    }
```